# Iphone google plus stream page

Tags: google-plus

How does stream page of google plus works on iphone, where you can slide the view left to right or vice versa (Nearby - Circles - Incoming). Is there any native control or sample codes?

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509393/duplicating-android-viewpager-type-functionality-with-menus-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you can use the Google API Objective-C Client to call the Google+ APIs.

Client Library:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Sample Code:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FPlusSample